# How do I share a node-red app developed in Bluemix?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm new to bluemix / node-red.  I have developed a trial app and got it working.  Now I'd like to share it with some others for review / modification in their bluemix environments.
Is there an direct way to package up the entire node-red application, including the flows (there is a fair bit of html/javascript) and some images ?  I used git to get the images into the node-red file structure but it does not seem to sync the actual flows.  I realize that the flows are normally stored in Cloudant for runtime reasons but it seems that there ought to be an orderly transfer method (besides cut/paste) especially for moving from (say) dev-->test-->prod.

Comment: Thank you for addressing exactly what I'm looking for.  This IBM Cloud doesn't seem production-ready in so many ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can export your node-red flow as a `json` file and share it. Others can import this `json` file and they will be able to see your flow.

To export your node-red flow:

1) In the UI select all nodes you want to export (selected nodes will have a red border)

2) Click on the top-right menu (three parallel lines just after the deploy button) and select Export->Clipboard

3) Copy the json file from the "Export nodes to clipboard" window and save a file

To import the json file, follow similar steps but select Import->Clipboard and paste the json file content to import the nodes.

Comment: Yes - I understand how to export the flows. My question is really about packaging up the flows and any other "artifacts".  For example if I use a template and include HTML that uses images - I can place those images in the application file structure (e.g. /public/images/).

Comment: No sure if I understood your comment, but could please post a more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve in your question? If you have images in public/images you will have to zip up your public images directory and send to others you want to share.

Comment: Bluemix, allows the use if git (which is how I added the images in the first place) to sync back and forth.  As far as I can tell the node-red flows are not part of this sync mechanism.  If they were then git would provide a decent way to "point" others to the app and try it out, with a simple "import".

I'm wondering if there is some other way ?  Or is Node-Red not that mature and relies on "steam driven" approaches ?  From what you said earlier - it seem the later is currently true.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the flows can't be stored in the deployed application file system image because it would get thrown away with every time the app is restaged (either due to a update or getting moved between hosting servers by the underlying Cloud Foundry/Bluemix system)

If you export the flow you want to share with your colleges and check it into your git repo in to `defaults/flow.json` when they clone the repo and deploy it will start with your flow in place. Any updates they make will be saved to the bound Cloudant instance so it will survive app updates.

This is mentioned in the README.md from the [node-red-bluemix-starter](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix-starter) project.

EDIT:
The Node-RED flow storage system is also [plugable](http://nodered.org/docs/api/storage/), so you could always implement your own git based flow storage engine if you wanted.

Comment: So there's no "anatomy of a node-red application repository"?  I wish they made clear in all their trumpet blowing documentation that all you can do is set up a repo and pipeline that delivers nothing until you script your own deployment.